# Создание рандома с шансом выпадения

Tags: алгоритм, случайные-числа, любой-язык

Задумался о том, как делаются рандомы с шансом выпадения.
К примеру есть три числа и у каждого разный шанс выпадения:

```
1 - 0.1
2 - 0.3
3 - 0.6
```

Как реализуются такие случайные числа?
Мне в голову пришло что-то такое

```
|0.1|----0.3----|----------0.6----------|
[ 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 3 ]
```

То есть брать массив из значений, повторять их столько раз, каков шанс их выпадения, ну, и пройтись по массиву обычным генератором случайных чисел.

Но мне кажется, что это не так работает)

Comment: Скажите только, как вы хотите получить вероятность 90+50+30=170%?

Comment: @Harry, это как пример)

Comment: Это не пример, таких примеров не бывает.

Comment: @Harry, а также ещё один важный момент: вероятность в процентах **не** исчисляется) Вероятность всегда есть дробь

Comment: @K А что такое символ процента, как не сокращение умножения на 0.01? Так что те же 60% - это просто другая запись 0.6...

Comment: @Harry, начнём с того, что так Вы просто проделываете лишние действия: для чего сначала умножать число на 100? Чтобы потом опять делить его на эти же 100? Потом перейдём к следующему: у процентов, если позволите так выразиться, в принципе иная *идеология*. 170% очень как может быть (скажем, от нормы производства). А вот вероятность 1.7 - нет. Процент - часть чего-либо, которую мы можем взять и повторить `N` раз, где на `N` формально нет ограничений. А какую часть Вы возьмёте от и без того части некого множества событий? Это какая-то логическая бессмыслица

Comment: @Harry, дело не в результате, а в логике, которую мы считываем из записи. Вспомните, кстати, логику и операторы `<->` (*тогда и только тогда*) и `=` (*эквивалентность*, символа нужного на клаве не нашёл)). У них идентичная таблица истинности. Замени мы их в любой формуле, результат же не поменяется. Все дело именно в том смысле, какой они несут при записи в данном контексте

Comment: @Harry, да и это не мои придирки, а общепринятая форма записи в математическом мире. Ведь вероятность есть `мера на множестве событий, принимающая значение от 0 до 1`. Так что так что) А вообще, для подобных дискуссий хорошо бы иметь русскую математику на просторах SE. Но увы ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку у вас не указан язык, будем считать, что есть только некий обобщенный генератор `rand()`, генерирующий случайные действительные числа от 0 до 1 (если это целые числа от 0 до `RAND_MAX`, как в C - то просто делите `double(rand())/RAND_MAX`).

Если вы умерите ваше ТЗ до обычных 100%, то решение будет предельно простым: если сгенерированное значение меньше первого порога, то вернуть первое значение, иначе если меньше второго - вернуть второе, иначе...

Считайте, что это - псевдокод:

```
int get_r()
{
    double r = rand();
    if (r < 0.10) return 1;
    if (r < 0.40) return 2;
    return 3;
}
```

Собственно, вот и все...

Comment: Думаю, нужно уточнить у ТС, нужно ли ему задавать числа и вероятность к ним динамически

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Это - детали реализации, на каждом языке свои. Смешно писать код, например, для какой-нибудь теоремы косинусов...

Comment: хм. И то верно ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: А как будет выглядеть реализация для случая вероятности  >1 (100%)

Comment: По-моему, сегодня день открытых дверей сами знаете где... :( Осеннее равноденствие так действует?

Comment: Сказали "А" ("Если вы умерите ваше ТЗ до обычных 100%...") говорите и "Б" )

Comment: @AlTheOne Вы, наверное, не видели, что изначально у автора была сумма вероятностей 170%. А вы, если сказали "А", говорите и "Б" - напечатайте тут "Войну и мир"...

Comment: Если ответ опирается на пример автора, то стоит изменить 0.3 на 0.4. Можно еще добавить, что для большого количества исходов придётся выбрать более эффективный поиск интервала - например, бинарный.

Comment: @MBo Спасибо, с примером вы правы, конечно.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Вы зря откатили правку - для набора `0.1, 0.3, 0.6` второй случай соответствует `0.1 + 0.3`

Comment: @MBo, упс. Согласен, мой косяк

Answer (score 1):

> То есть брать массив из значений, повторять их столько раз, каков шанс их выпадения, ну, и пройтись по массиву обычным генератором случайных чисел.

Совршенно верно. Это вполне правильный способ, с той только разницей, что создавать явный массив не обязательно.

В общем случае, если ваш генератор случайных чисел генерирует равномерно распределенные значения в диапазоне, скажем `[0, R)`, то вы просто домножаете требуемые вероятности на величину `R` и затем просто проверяете, в какой из получившихся поддипапазонов попадает очередное полученное случайное значение.

В вашем случае таких поддиапазонов будет всего лишь три и можно просто выполнить проверку через лесенку `if`. Если поддиапазонов больше (или из количество не известно на стадии компиляции), то придется использовать какое-то более хитрое программное представление этих поддипапазонов. При определенных условиях это может быть и массив.